# Node Regex Match Comments in file

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, fs, jsdoc

I am trying to read comments from js files. I am reading the file and comparing against the regex but for the life of me can't figure out how to only read comments that start with `@SimpleSwagger`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(file, { encoding: 'utf8' });
var regexResults = fileContent.match(jsDocRegex);

 /**
 * @SimpleSwagger
 * Model:
 *   name: Car
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you want first of change the file content into array like this:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var fileContent = fs.readFileSync("peking.txt", { encoding: 'utf8' });
var splitSimpleSwagger=fileContent.split(/@SimpleSwagger/).filter(function(token){
return token != ""
})
console.log(splitSimpleSwagger)
//this will return 2 array which is the word above string @SimpleSwagger and the word
//after @SimpleSwagger like this:
//[ 'var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(file, { encoding: \'utf8\' });\nvar 
//regexResults = fileContent.m
//atch(jsDocRegex);\n\n /**\n * ',                                                                     
//'\n * Model:\n *   name: Car\n */' ]
//so if you want to get only this '\n * Model:\n *   name: Car\n */' just do this:
console.log(splitSimpleSwagger[1])
//then you will get the contain of the comment after word '@SimpleSwagger' which is
//'\n * Model:\n *   name: Car\n */'
//and if you want to clean that up just do this:
console.log(splitSimpleSwagger[1].split("*").join("").replace("/",""))
//it will return
```

Model:
    name: Car